# Is there a way to automatically reconnect to a server when the connection is lost?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have an afk fish farm. However, sometimes my connection drops and my night long afk session is ruined. Is there a way to create an auto rejoiner for 1.9 so I can continue to afk if this happens?

It would also be ideal if such a program would also allow you to hold down right click, as I would be unable to reapply my macro.

Comment: There's a hacked client for this: I recommend _Wurst_ or _Argon_ these have Anti-Afk and wurst has auto rejoin my default

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to download a program that has a rejoinder built-in. I don't personally go hacking on Minecraft servers however, the Wurst hacked client (yes that is the real name of it.) offers a lot of game improving options too. (if you don't want to hack. But seriously, why would you.) It has a built in rejoinder and optifine so you can zoom in and your game runs smoother. It also has a button you can press to get rid of all outdated servers or ones with lost connection. I would recommend downloading it even if you don't want to hack. Here is an instructional video on how to download it:

If you don't want to watch the video than go to the website shown in the video and look at the instructions there.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to not use a hacking client but thanks. Is there any way to reapply a hold tight click macro so I can continue auto fishing?

Comment: @AllenF.  As server owner....I would not recommend you this solution. If you show up with this on my server, you would get banned right away. Same with afk-fishing, which I would consider as cheating, too.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík I happen to be on a server where that is not the case. However, I agree about using a hack client

Comment: @AllenF. Well, every server can have its own rules, of course. That is purely on you to know them and if you obey them. Still just a little warning is in place, I think.

Comment: Just cause it's a hacked client doesn't mean you're hacking, you don't have to. It was just a suggestion. But having a hacked client doesn't mean you're a hacker. You can choose not to use the bad features and use things like auto server joiners and instant optifine!

Answer (score -1):

The 5zig mod will rejoin the server after being kicked, and it is **not** a hacked client, and supports 1.9. Download it here: https://5zig.eu/

Comment: Does it support 1.8 also?

Comment: Yes, just click the version for 1.8